# Swift CollectionView sorting disorder

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a `UICollectionView` nested in another `ParentCollectionView` , the problem is when i set data to it the data gets disordered. The Section Headers are set in order but the nested collection view is not in order. 
Here's the code

```
import UIKit


class HomeView: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet weak var parentCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    let viewModel = HomeVM()
    var categories = [ServiceSection]()
    var categoriesReversed = [[String:Any]]()
    var collectionViewTags = Int()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.categories = [ServiceSection(
            section:
                ["id":"2","name":"planet","service":[
                ["id":"1","name":"Sun"]
                    ]
            ]
            ),
            ServiceSection(
                            section:
                            ["id":"2","name":"Animal","service":[
                                ["id":"1","name":"Dog"]
                                ]
                            ])
        ,

            ServiceSection(
                section:
                ["id":"2","name":"Daries","service":[
                ["id":"1","name":"Milk"]
                    ]
                ])
        ,

            ServiceSection(
                section:
                ["id":"2","name":"Meet","service":[
                    ["id":"1","name":"Steak"]
                    ]
                ])

        ]


        let height = (self.parentCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height)

        self.collectionViewHeight.constant = height
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        if (collectionView == parentCollectionView)
        {
            return self.categories.count
        }
        else
        {
            collectionView.tag = collectionViewTags
            collectionViewTags += 1
            return 1
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if (collectionView == parentCollectionView){
            return 1
        }else{
            let section = self.categories[collectionView.tag].services
            return section.count

        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        if (collectionView == parentCollectionView){
            return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "parentCell", for: indexPath)
        }
        else
        {
            let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell


            let collection = self.categories[collectionView.tag].services
            let cellData = collection[indexPath.row]
            cell.title.text = cellData.name

            return cell
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        if collectionView == parentCollectionView{

            return CGSize(width: parentCollectionView.frame.width, height: 30)

        }
        return CGSize(width:150,height:80)

    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        if parentCollectionView == collectionView {

            let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "header", for: indexPath) as! CollectionHeader
            header.header.text = self.categories[indexPath.section].name
            return header
        }

        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }


}
```

Comment: You need ordered by what?

Comment: Ordered by their order in the data source  . Please look at the section header and the section content and compare them to the data source they mismatch

Answer (score 1):

**Update :**

For anyone looking into this this the mentioned technique is not valid and shouldn't not be used , it's like fighting the OS .
The way the iOS Tables/Collections work is by reusing cells
So For example if Cell "A" contains some data and user scroll past it then rather than creating new Cell "B" the OS takes the already rendered cell and just changes it's content based on the data passed to the `CellForItem(At` function.

Nowadays i recommend looking into Diffable datasource to ease the state management for the data and automatically handles the updates for sections and items.
*https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdiffabledatasource*

**Explanation**: The problem was I set the height of the `collectionView` in the storyboard to "100" because I am setting it dynamically later anyway (after the `collectionView` loads), however, this causes pretty weird behavior of not loading the view correctly when using `reloadData()`. I guess what the OS is trying to do is only care about the part on that is visible on the screen.

The second problem was that for some reason (unknown to me) I have to do reload sections using the `numberOfSection` as parameter that I got from the previously called reloadData, I don't know why do I need to reload each section (I'd love to vote up for someone who can explain it)

**Simply**: The `collectionView` depends on the height and height depends on the `collectionView`.

**The Solution :** I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it, but it works for me, I changed the collectionView height to 9000 or any big number so the OS knows it needs to load the whole thing and after calling `reloadData()` correct the height.

```
self.parentCollectionView.reloadData()

let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (0,  self.parentCollectionView.numberOfSections))
let indexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: range)
self.parentCollectionView.reloadSections(indexSet)
        
let height = (self.parentCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height)
self.collectionViewHeight.constant = height
```

Comment: It's great! thanks a lot